# Error para importar partials sass con gulp

Tags: html5, gulp, sass, gulp-sass

Ojala me entiendan  y puedan ayudarme, tengo esa estructura en un proyecto estoy trabajando con Gulp, gulp-sass, browser-Sync; se supone que sass la documentarion dice que se puede crear partials añadiendo el subrayado para que importes pero no se compile en un archivo css aparte entonces eso estoy haciendo, creando un archivo _variables.scss y mi archivo principal es main.scss, todo corre normal hago un cambio y mi navegador se refresca gracias a browser-sync pero pasa algo extraño que si realizo dos o tres cambios seguidos en ese archivo _variables.scss lo q esta compilando normal como se ve en la imagen de consola empieza a salir un error que no halla el archivo importado .. como hago yo quiero importar de esa manera. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Task BrowserSync
gulp.task('serve',['sass'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: "./app"
    });
    gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});


// Task compile sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/main.scss')
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});
```

Comment: ¿Has añadido la opción `includePaths` a la función `sass` en el gulpfile? Edita tu pregunta y añade el código del gulpfile.

Comment: desconozco de esa opcion.. voy a editar la pregunta para añadir el gulpfile :D

Comment: Haz algo, mueve `_variables.scss`  a `scss/partials` y añade lo siguiente a `sass`: `{ includePaths: ['scss/partials'] }`. Es importante que sigas importando directamente `variables.css` y no `partials/variable.scss`.

Comment: Esto me ocurria mucho al poner los archivos en el mismo directorio y no separarlos por carpetas modulares, si lo vas a dejar asi, intenta poner antes del archivo que quieres compilar el `./` eso le dira al script que esta dentro de la misma carpeta, y deberia de quedar asi `@import "./variables"`

Answer (score 0):

Esta importando mal, debería ser

```
"_variables"
```

y tú has puesto

```
"variables"
```

Comment: Desde la actualizacion del 2018, ya no es necesario poner el guion bajo